# How can I resolve a 3DS networking issue?

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-x-y, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, networking

I can't seem to connect my pokemon x game to my network, even though I have tried using both my guest network and my secure network. **Both** of them are WPA secured (I believe, I can't check right now, but will as soon as possible), but I was able to connect and receive the Torchic promo gift on my pokemon y game. I **have** attempted using a 3DS that had been broken (only the lower half of the top screen, so I just replicated my actions to attempt to connect, and I could still see the error message), but that refused to connect also.

***Both*** 3DS can connect to the network and use the Internet browser, and streetpass works fine, the *only* issue is connecting to the network in game. The error message goes along the lines of "error, could not connect to the network" (might have been "connection refused"). I have also tried using Internet to connect to GTS and the streetpass connection thing, but neither of those work on either game, on either 3ds, even though it used to on pokemon y.

I am super confused over this, as the issue just popped up, seemingly overnight. I really want to claim the torchic ASAP, because the promo ends after December, and although that is a ways off, waiting until the end to fix this would pass up being able to own a valuable promo, who is super powerful besides.

Does anybody know how to fix this? I am very sorry if I didn't make myself clear, or if I didn't supply enough information, but I can't access either my own router or either game right now, and I have no clue how to trouble shoot on a 3ds anyways. *If I need to collect more information, please comment what I need and I will get it as soon as I can.*

Comment: Ouch.  That sounds a bit wonky.  I know I've run into a couple issues connecting to the Internet through Pokemon Y a couple times, but just trying again works fine.

Comment: have you tried power cycling?  To do so, remove the power cord to your modem and router for 30 seconds, plug them back in and try again.

Comment: @turbo Alright, I'll try this out as soon as I get home.

Comment: Temporary work-around - go to a Starbucks, Best Buy or other Nintendo Zone provider.

Comment: @TheUgly It's very possibly not the end-all solution, but any time you are having networking problems it's worth a shot. I agree with KatieK as well, you should try it on a different WLAN.  If it's both games now, that means it's your home network or your DS and likely not the game.  Have you tried any non-Pokemon games as well?  It could be a server issue, although that's unlikely since it seems to just be you experiencing this. Eliminate as many variables as possible.

Comment: If someone would like to turn these comments into an answer, I think it's thorough enough to justify one.

Comment: I had this same exact problem but ended up fixing it. When I first launched Pokemon X it had me do an update to my 3DS. Then it wouldn't let me connect to the GTS or anything. I ended up just deleting my internet connections in my 3DS settings, turned my 3DS off and back on, then went back in and added my internet connection back in. After that, it has been working wonderfully!

Comment: @TheUgly Did it work?  All I provided was basic network trouble shooting, which IMO doesn't justify an answer as it is possibly a deeper issue.

Comment: I didn't test it yet, I had a bit of a hectic night. I'm going to get I done tonight though

Comment: its not your wifi or your ds is at fault there has been many people having problems regards to this issue. I tried other games and other 3ds services and they are working fine its just the games that wont connect. since the release of these Pokémon games X&Y there has been faults it will take some time to work out all the bugs and hopefully all of us can enjoy the online experience with these games

Comment: it could be a parental control issue.  You have to do a lot of toggling with parental controls to enable some of the simplest things.  Wouldn't hurt to check this.

Answer (score 1):

The pokemon X/Y game had several updates, what you need to do is go to the Eshop and download the updates.

Nintendo 3DS games don't updates their games on its own unlike other consoles and PC and that is probably the cause of your connection error.

I had the exact problem with the first update.

Answer (score 0):

well i would try power cycling or restart the router if that does not work try updates if that does not work either check if your router and modem are plugged in, if nothing works try nintendo support or refer to the instruction booklet.